# What is wrong with my mysql insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `liftcentrale`(`timedate`,`vraagaanbod`, `date`, `from_place`, `to_place`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `smoke`, `extra`, `freeyesno`, `price_euro`, `firsttimeryesno`, `seats_offered`)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\'$vraagaanbod\',\'$date\',\'$from_place\',\'$to_place\',\'$name\',\'$email\',\'$gender\',\'$smoke\',\'$extra\',\'$freeyesno\',\'$price_euro\',\'$firsttimeryesno\',\'$seats_offered\');";

echo $sql; //CHECK QUERY STRING

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I tried using phpMyAdmin to create php statements. Changed the single parentheses that phpMyAdmin created for 'normal' ones. Tried and tested over & again. Can't find a working solution otherwise would not be here. For some reason, I can not even see the query string.

Comment: What does `$conn->error` say?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes when you're using double quotes as the string delimiters.

Comment: If you don't see the output of `echo $sql;` then you're probably getting a syntax error somewhere. Check your PHP error log on the server.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: try this: $sql = "INSERT INTO `liftcentrale`(`timedate`,`vraagaanbod`, `date`, `from_place`, `to_place`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `smoke`, `extra`, `freeyesno`, `price_euro`, `firsttimeryesno`, `seats_offered`)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$vraagaanbod\','$date','$from_place','$to_place','$name','$email','$gender','$smoke','$extra','$freeyesno','$price_euro','$firsttimeryesno','$seats_offered')";

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '". $value1 ."', '". $value2 ."');";
```

Comment: I still get an error msg after using Sankar's solution, "Error: INSERT INTO `liftcentrale` (`timedate`, `vraagaanbod`, `date`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '', '');"

Comment: In the MySQL DB I use a column 'LiftID' which auto increments. I use a form with POST method and fields that I use with these lines: $name=($_REQUEST['name']);  
$email=($_REQUEST['email']);   
$date=($_REQUEST['date']);     
$from_place=($_REQUEST['from_place']);
$to_place=($_REQUEST['to_place']);    
$vraagaanbod=($_REQUEST['vraagaanbod']);   
Hope together with Stack Overflow we can use this and provide a great service!

Comment: I found the error log, which has 'command not found' in every line.

Comment: php_error.log says: 'Undefined variable: mysqli' ?? something in my installation must have failed. But the setup log doesn't show errors.

Comment: mysql error log says 'Unknown database 'liftcentrale''

Answer (score 0):

Checking my error logs definitely helped, after I installed MAMP on my own laptop to see what these logs said. DB name was wrong, and the date format. I now can insert data into MySQL. Thanks for all the help!